# Rest Api - Given the following output, what would be the correct url format?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, api

Say I was building a rest api that produced the following output given the below url:

/owner/123/animal

{
    {
       Owner: 123,
       Animal: Cat
    },
    {
       Owner: 123,
       Animal: Dog
    },
    { 
       Owner: 123,
       Animal: Walrus
    }
}

What would be a Restful way to just get all animals a particular owner owned back? As in, what would the urllook like?

{
    Owner: 123
    Animals: { Cat, Rat, Walrus}
}

Or would it just be better to have the client parse the first json output?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what characters you put into the URI. Any advice given is only an opinion therefore. What matters more is that the URI is given a meaningful relation name (like in the Web where a URI is annotated with a human friendly text given the link some useful meaning). A client should never need to interpret the segments in the URI to determine the intent of it nor should a client think of an URI (or the resource it points to) to [return a specific type](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your API client adds the `123` in the `/owner/123/animal`, I would argue he is already aware for whom he is requesting the animals, so adding the `owner` field at all in the response might be redundant.

My suggestion would be to return a list of animals at the `/owner/123/animal` URL. In Spring, the definition would look as follows.

```
@RestController
public class OwnerController {

    @GetMapping(value = "owner/{ownerId}/animal")
    public List<Animal> getAnimalsForOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") Long id) {

    }

}
```

And a sample response would be `[ {"name": "First"}, {"name": "Second"} ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
/owner/123/animals
```

It should return only list animals.
For example

```
[{name:'cat';age:'6 month'},{name:'dog';age:'8 month'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

/owner/123/animal

This url should return animals owned by owner with id 123.
I would prefer to use animals instead of animal. 
GET /owner/123/animals

Response : List of animals

```
[
  {
    "name": "Cat",
    "color": "Grey"
  },
  {
    "name": "Dog",
    "color": "Black"
  }
]
```

You can also give ability to consumer to choose the response data

GET /owner/123/animals ? include=name

response can be

```
[
  {
    "name": "Cat"
  },
  {
    "name": "Dog"
  }
]
```

OR

```
{
  "names": "cat,Dog"
}
```